# Struts2 Ajax issue

Tags: ajax, struts2

The problem is the following. When user clicks on the link I load the data into a div, but when the session of the user is expired I need to redirect him to login page, or if the is external error I need to redirect the user to error page. The problem is, if for example my interceptor sees that the user is no longer in session and tries to redirect him to login page, the login page is again loaded in the div. the other elements on page remain. How can I make the page reload without JavaScript? I mean directly from struts.xml.

Comment: You need to return something from your filter when it's an XHR request, or set an error code (I prefer this, but it depends on your needs). Your requesting JS code can then redirect to the logon page.

Answer (score 0):

You need to send to your browser whether it is a new session or not.

One way.

In your interceptor add a header to indicate whether it is a new session. Then if you are using jquery you can bind the ajax complete and check the header for the attribute that its a new session. And finally on new session, do a location.reload.

your ajax for jquery would look something like this

```
    jQuery(document).ajaxComplete(function(e, xhr, settings) {

        var status = xhr.status;
        if(status == 200 ){
            var isAuth = xhr.getResponseHeader('_isnewsession');

            if((isAuth == '1')){
                alert('Your Session has timed out!');
                location.reload();
            }
        }
    });
```

Does that make sense?

Comment: Thank for quick reply, but expired session is not the only case. There are error windows and access denied window which also must not be loaded into the div where ajax result is being displayed, they must be loaded in the whole window. I'm also curios, if it can be done by struts only, without javascript.

Comment: I dont think you can avoid javascript. You would have to send error and access info to the browser, you could send exception information only as json, by setting you error result to json and add error/denied information there. But you still need js to evaluate the response and instruct the browser.